# Increasing mass

Tags: solutions, concentration

I'm watching a video, and the speaker states that the molality formula is better than the molarity formula because it is more constant, since molarity deals with volume and molality deals with mass. If someone adds more solvent than the volume changes, so the answer in molarity changes as well. But if more solvent is added, doesn't the mass increase as well?

Comment: You can never really say one's better than the other; they're different things. Mind providing a link to the video? In both formulas, adding solute would change the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think someone may have made a slip of the tongue there: if you add more ***solute***, the volume of the solution will change, without changing the mass of solvent present. If you just add more solvent, of course you'll change both the molarity and the molality.

Let's do a bit of a thought experiment to illustrate this: I have some toluene and I'd like to dissolve a whole bunch of tri-octylphosphine sulfur into it (don't worry if you don't know what these are, just remember that toluene is the solvent and TOPS is the solute).

Let's say I want to make a 1 molal solution. The definition of one molal is a mole of solute in a kilogram of **solvent**. I measure out one mole of TOPS and dissolve it in 1 kg of toluene. Done!

Now I want to make a 1 molar solution. The definition of one molar is a mole of solute in a liter of **solution**. I might be tempted to measure out one liter of toluene, dissolve the TOPS in it, and call it a day.

I would be wrong.

The reason is because one mole TOPS takes up a certain amount of volume. A rough estimate is that it takes up about a third of a liter. My solution is now one mole of TOPS in **1.33 liters of solution**, making it 0.75 molar instead of 1 molar!

I can fix this by starting out with the TOPS, then slowly adding toluene until the total volume of everything is 1L. This will give me a 1 molar solution.

You can extend this idea a little further to see that adding solute to a solution makes its molarity a **mess** to calculate unless you pretend that the solution volume doesn't change. The molality, meanwhile, is easy, because the mass of solvent hasn't changed a whit.

EDIT: As Martin points out, molality has an additional benefit in that solutions naturally expand as they heat. If we heat a solution up, its volume will increase, and its molarity will change. The molality, however, will not, since the mass of solvent does not depend on temperature.

Comment: I got a bit carried away explaining this. Sorry...

Comment: It is worthwhile to state, that mass does not change with the temperature, while volume usually does.